# Java classpath (-cp) and passing execution to that class

Tags: java, jar

I am relatively new to Java but have a fair understanding about how the class path works with respect to providing a list of folder and jars that make classes available to other classes.

I have compiled a JAR (lets say example.jar) that has a main function where execution normally begins. Sometimes I want execution to begin in a different class (lets say myAlternateClass.java), with its own main. I can achieve this by doing using the -cp argument when executing the jar, for example;

```
java -cp example.jar myAlternateClass
```

This works as I require but I am unsure of what exactly is happening here.

Comment: You're invoking only `myAlternateClass` while having `example.jar` on the classpath.  If `myAlternateClass` doesn't *need* anything from that JAR, then having it on the classpath is a misnomer; it doesn't really need to be there.  In general, you'd invoke the main class from within the JAR via `java -jar example.jar` instead.

Comment: The JVM is loading "example.jar" into the system class loader. Then the JVM runs the main from "myAlternateClass."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on exactly what you're looking for, but I'll give it a shot.

There are two ways to use a jar file. If the jar file has a Main-Class specified in its META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file, then you can load java with the jar file and execution will start in the main method of that class.

`java -jar example.jar`

On the other hand, a jar file can simply be loaded onto the classpath, which makes all of the classes within it available for use. This is the example you are giving:

`java -cp example.jar org.somewhere.MySecondClass`

The `-cp example.jar` puts all of the classes within the jar on the class path and the second argument `org.somewhere.MySecondClass` gives the class at which execution should begin. This second argument would have to be within the jar since specifying a classpath overrides the default (which is just the current directory). In this case, java ignores any Main-Class specified in the MANIFEST.MF file of the jar (if one even is specified).

Multiple jar files as well as directories of java files not in a jar can be specified by putting colons between them. So,

`java -jar example.jar:. MyClass`

could launch MyClass from the current directory, but place example.jar on the classpath so that MyClass could create instances of whatever classes are available within example.jar.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I was looking for and makes complete sense. Thank you.

Comment: Cool. Glad to have helped. Happy coding.